# How to create a function to check for property of an object in javascript, and set it if it's not there

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have this code...

```
var suitcase = {
    shirt: "Hawaiian"
};

var checkProp = function(obj, prop, val){
if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    console.log(obj.prop);
} else {
    obj.prop = val;
    console.log(obj.prop);
}
};
checkProp("suitcase","shorts","blue");
```

and when I run it, it returns undefined. On the surface it looks fine. No syntax problems or similar things like that. What would I have to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

`suitcase` is a var, not a string. Instead, it should read

```
checkProp(suitcase,'shorts','blue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Object` itself, not it's name:

```
checkProp(suitcase,"shorts","blue");
```

Also, use `obj[prop]` instead of `obj.prop`.
(With `obj.prop`, you're accessing the `prop` property of the object, literally, not the property you're looking for.)

Other than that, your code works. It could be shortened like this, though:

```
var checkProp = function(obj, prop, val){
    obj[prop] = obj[prop] || val; // If obj[prop] exists, set it to itself (does nothing), otherwise, set it's content to `val`.
    console.log(obj.prop);
};
```

Comment: this would not work the way he has implemented it if `prop` was on `obj` prototype, he is checking for the prop on the object itself only.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably obj[prop] instead of obj.prop

Answer (score 0):

You have a few different options but I think your solution may work. It just has a small error. In your call to your function:

```
checkProp('suitcase', 'shorts', 'blue);
```

You have `"suitcase"` defined as a string when it should be an object. Try fixing that and see if it works.

**Edit:**

Another option you could try would be this:

```
var checkProp = function(obj, prop, val){
    if(obj) {
        if(!obj[prop]) {
            obj[prop] = val;
        }
        if(window.console && window.console.log) {
            console.log(obj[prop]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What browsers don't support `console / console.log` that you'd have to check for that? o.O That seems to be a bit out of scope for this question.

Comment: I like your function. It's a bit more concise. My function is rather long-winded. Plus, you have checks in your function for support of logging to the console, a very useful thing.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've had trouble with IE 9. The debugger doesn't attach automatically and if I don't have the developer tools opened it was throwing an error. It's just an extra check. It is a little out of scope but I'd rather post an answer that will work in all browsers. It also could be my settings are a little different. Either way, its better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks. I didn't think your solution was long winded. It definitely made since and I imagine it worked quite nicely. I'm just so weary of console.log throwing an error (thanks IE 9) now that I usually wrap it just to be sure. Never a good thing to see red error text in the console. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
var suitcase = {
    shirt: "Hawaiian"
};

var checkProp = function(obj, prop, val){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        console.log(obj[prop]);
    } else {
        obj[prop] = val;
        console.log(obj[prop]);
    }
};
checkProp(suitcase,"shorts","blue");
```